# веб-сокеты - открыть соединение к определенному пользователю

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, websocket

пытаюсь понять, как происходит обмен сообщениями между людьми

ведь при каждом обновлении страницы создается новый объект соединения`WebSocket'a`...

как собственно получить возможность оповещать определенного пользователя о событиях, если он не будет сидеть на одном месте? то есть, будет переключать страницы, и будут создаваться новые и новые объекты `WS`

Comment: Может быть, использовать для навигации ajax-запросы и History API? Заодно поотзывчивее будет.

Comment: если пользователь авторизуется на странице - надо создать механизм привязки соединения с именем пользователя , по имени пользователя выбирать соединение и по нему отправлять сообщение(как правило при переключении между страницами одного сайта - авторизация не теряется)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584515/websocket-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F очень похожий вопрос