# WebSocket - Как правильно хранить соединения?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, websocket

Стало непонятно:

при каждом обновлении страницы у пользователя, на сервере создается новый объект соединения..

*Вопрос:* **Как держать этот объект актуальным?**

Пришло в голову хранить это соединение в `БД` и при создании нового соединения, обновлять значение из этой `БД` для определенного пользователя... то есть, есть некая структура:

```
user_id | socket
     34 |  {obj}
```

есть пользователь с идентификатором `34`, у него есть свой объект соединения `ws`, который храниться в `socket`, и как я уже говорил, - при каждом создании нового соединения, будет обновляться значения из поля `socket`

скажите правильно ли это?

**P.S. Для сайта вопросов-ответов**

Comment: вполне, только использовать базу для этого нет необходимости - достаточно объекта в памяти.

Comment: минусование без объянения причины - глупое действие. для использования websocket данный вопрос очень актуальный.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! а как мне различать эти объекты? какой объект к какому юзеру относиться? использовать пару "ключ: значение"?

Comment: да, типа такого: логин:соединение. или как вариант, если имеется возможность, прописать имя в самом коннекте , как дополнительное значение.

Comment: только надо учитывать безопасность - заносить в этом "массив" ключ:значение только тогда когда есть ключ, т.е. юзер залогинился. в противном случае обрывать коннект

Answer (score 3):

> Пришло в голову хранить это соединение в БД

Хо-хо-о! Эм, нет, это плохая идея. Соединение вещь очень контекстная для **конкретного процесса** и её не стоит класть в общедоступное хранилище, т. к. если его заберёт оттуда другой процесс, он не получит работающего соединения, поскольку ОС выделяла ресурсы на это другому процессу.

...это при условии, если у вас получится объект соединения **сериализовать** в последовательность байт для записи в БД (база ведь хранит *данные*). А скорее всего, вся затея оборвётся уже на этом этапе, т. к. вы просто не сможете получить необходимых для воспроизведения данных *даже в рамках того же процесса*.

Плюс надо иметь в виду, что пользователь может находиться на сайте **с нескольких вкладок и/или даже устройств одновременно**, и наверное, вам нужно уметь держать несколько активных соединений на одного пользователя сразу. Вы уже чувствуете этот дух приключений?

Если вы работаете всего с одним процессом, то вы можете хоть в глобальном объекте их хранить. Нечто похожее `socket.io` и делает по умолчанию, а `socket.io-express-session` из ответа @Darth вам поможет быстрее сопоставлять пользователей и соединения.

Но это ещё не конец истории, **если ваше приложение работает в нескольких процессах**. Потому что пользователь, подключившись к процессу, висит только на нём. Послать сообщение ему в соединение из другого процесса вашего же приложения будет невозможно. Для этого придуман `socket.io-adapter` (абстрактный) и его реализации, например [`socket.io-redis`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis), дающий связь между процессами приложения через Redis. В этом случае свои соединения каждый процесс всё равно хранит где-то у себя, в глобальном объекте, но другие процессы даже при этом всё равно могут к ним обращаться.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [socket.io-express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-express-session). 
Тогда вы сможете пользоваться всеми преимуществами сессий и вам не надо будет придумывать велосипед, для того чтобы каждый раз передать id юзера при переподключении